# How can I use goto to perform a task for a file instead of using a function?

Tags: c++, if-statement, fstream, ifstream, goto

So I've always heard that using **goto** makes you a terrible person, so I've never really experimented with it until recently. For fun, I decided to make a program that *HEAVILY* relies on **goto** statements to see for myself when they can actually come in handy.

In other words, I am purposely trying to stay away from anything generally accepted as good programming, and I'm experimenting with other methods...

That being said, I ran into my first issue. I want to read from a file, and emulate a "function" by simply transferring the data I gathered to another part of my code.. run it through... and return back to the file.

Here is some of my code so you can get the basic idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string command, fileName, fileLine;

    while (command != "quit")
    {
        cout << "cmd> ";
        cin >> command;

        if (command == "function")
        {
            FUNCTION: // I want to manipulate the data I gather from the file here.

            cout << "Perform a certain task here instead of using a function." << endl;

            goto FILE;
        }

        else if (command == "file")
        {
            cout << "filename> ";
            cin >> fileName;

            ifstream myFile(fileName.c_str());

            if (myFile.is_open())
            {
                while (getline(myFile, fileLine))
                {
                    goto FUNCTION;

                    FILE:

                    cout << "You finished your task using the above 'if' statement." << endl;
                }

                myFile.close();
            }
        }

        else if (command == "quit")
            break;

        else
            cout << "Invalid Command." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile my code, I get the following errors:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:37:6: error: jump to label ‘FILE’ [-fpermissive]
example.cpp:21:9: error:   from here [-fpermissive]
example.cpp:29:13: error:   crosses initialization of ‘std::ifstream myFile’
```

It seems like I can't use **goto** to jump over the initialization of "**ifstream myFile**." Does anyone know a way, without using a function and without using any flags, that I can accomplish this task using **goto**?

Comment: When you `goto FUNCTION` `myFile` will be destroyed since it is going out of scope.  One way to avoid that is to dynamically allocate myFile rather than allocate it on the stack.  Don't know if that will get rid of the warning, though.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That's an interesting idea. Do you know how to declare an **ifstream** without assigning a file yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

Instead of writing:

```
ifstream myFile(fileName.c_str());
```

You should declare the [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) variable towards the top of `main()` like so:

```
ifstream myFile;
```

Then, after reading the file name, you should assign it to the input file stream:

```
myFile.open(fileName.c_str());
```

This will allow you use [`goto`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/#goto) to perform a task for a file instead of using a function (without running into the errors I was receiving).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as the compiler tells you... You can't skip the initialization of `ifstream myFile(fileName.c_str());` which is exactly what your goto statement attempts to accomplish. If you would ignore that warning you'd get to a situation where you might use `myFile` before it was allocated/initialized or after it was freed(which is very bad). I'd suggest you move the `if (command == "function")` code block inside the scope of `else if (command == "file")`.

A few general suggestions:

1) goto is heavily used in C code for cleanup. You can browse the linux kernel and see plenty of examples [1](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L254) [2](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1107) [3](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1543)

2) goto is bad in C and even worse in C++, because in C++ you have all kinds of implicit memory manipulations which you could easily avoid in C. So maybe you want to rewrite that code in C and then you'd get no error/warning.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply. I had no idea that I might be able to avoid the errors if I used straight C. I completely agree that **goto** is not a good choice, but luckily this program has absolutely no purpose other than to experiment with **goto** functions. I think that there definitely has to be a way to get this done with a **goto** though... Any other ideas to get this done with goto? I know there has to be a way.

Comment: Maybe I can declare **ifstream** at the beginning of the program, and dynamically allocate the file later? Is it possible to declare **ifstream** at the beginning without a file name?

Comment: Write in C... and use system API instead of ifstream(e.g. open, write, read, etc.) It will make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your example is that you skip `ifstream` constructor.

The true is: `GOTO` statement can be used under some conditions. For example according to **MISRA C++ 2008**

> Rule 6-6-1 (Required) Any label referenced by the GOTO statement shall
> be declared in the same block, on in a block enclosing the GOTO
> statement.
>
> Rule 6-6-2 (Required) The GOTO statement shall jump to a label
> declared later in the same function body.

These two rules are those most important, but there are others.

**Why these rules?**

The problem with GOTO is that it breaks the order the code is executed. The humans are very bad in imagining how a computer program will envolve in time. If you use GOTO, the program doesn't folow the line order but jumps. This is a reason of many terrible mistakes. See "GOTO Statement Considered Harmful" by E. W. Dijkstra.

**The cleanup**

GOTO is sometimes used for cleanup. However this is considered a bad style because one should rely on RAII idiom. For example when an exception is thrown, the cleanup may not be processed.

Comment: I understand that they are frowned upon, but the whole purpose of the program I'm making is to experiment with terrible practices. It really has no purpose other than to learn other ways of doing things (even if it's the wrong way). With that begin said, do you have any ideas on how to use **goto** to accomplish this task?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way. I will look into "GOTO Statement Considered Harmful" by E. W. Dijkstra at some point.